# Overriding equals() when using Lists in Java

Tags: java, list, duplicates, set, equals

I am in a bit of confusion. Suppose I have **class A** and some `List<A>` in some other **class B**.

So, because I am using a **list**, duplicates are allowed. Because duplicates are allowed (that means no comparison needed), do I have to override method **equals()** and **hashCode()** in class A?

So the emphasis here is on **List** (duplicates allowed - no need for comparison).

And I should override these 2 methods when I am using **Set** (duplicates NOT allowed - we need to define how objects will be compared)? (99% sure this is correct answer, just want to check it and make sure I got 100% correct answer for both: **List** and **Set**)

Note: I did not find answer on stack because no one asked excact same thing with using lists and duplicates allowed.

Comment: The question about `Set` should be a separate post, not bundled into this question.

Comment: Have you checked out those two? [Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2265503/12323248), [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27581/12323248)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not plan to ever compare any `A` objects to each other -- meaning you're neither using a `Set`, nor `List` methods like `indexOf` or `contains` -- then you do not need to implement `equals` or `hashCode`.

However, if you do ever intend to use `indexOf` or `contains` -- or if you plan to *test* your code, e.g. by asserting that the `A` in the `List` is equal to some expected `A` -- then you do need to implement `equals`, and it is poor practice to implement `equals` without also implementing `hashCode`.  You don't need a *good* implementation of `hashCode`, but you should have one.

Comment: Why I do not need to implement equals (and hashCode) when using Set? How Set will know what are duplicates? Based on what?

Comment: @Cluv: I believe you're misreading the answer, which says the opposite.  I've tweaked the wording to be clearer.

Comment: I meant this. Let's suppose I will not compare any A objects to each other. But I want to create Set<A> set = new Set<>(). After creating this Set "set", I want to just add 3 objects A to set. Also, let's suppose class A has 3 fields: a,b,c. Also suppose that 2 of these 3 added objects have the same a,b, and c fields.

My question is: How Set "set" will know that those 2 objects A are the same? Or "set" will not know - and he will store all of those 3 objects A

Comment: @Cluv , it's not that the comparison amongst the objects is required only while adding them into Sets. Let's say the Set has all the objects of Type A now that you wanted to add, later you invoke contains() for checking if some object is present in this set or not. To accomplish this a comparison will be done on the objects of Type A. If you do no specify the equals() then the default implementation (Object class) will be used, which is not generally we we would want

Comment: @Cluv: The set _won't_ know, and will store all three objects.  That's why `equals` and `hashCode` are necessary for _anything_ going into a `Set`.

Comment: @Cluv I think if you don't define `equals` and `hashCode` (together), then just the reference address is used with the default implementations, which will obviously always return "not equal" for objects that seem equal. Anyone, please feel free to correct me.

Comment: Yes, that is the answer I was supposing it was correct. Thanks!

Comment: Learning Java after C++ and that is why I have some doubts :)

Comment: And to make it clear. For JUST adding objects A in LIST, no equal and hashCode is needed? :)

Comment: As I stated: that's true...if you're not going to use `contains`, `indexOf`, or any other such method on that `List`, and not going to write tests that verify the contents of that list.

Comment: @Cluv Is your question answered at this point? Or is there anything unclear?